# How to convert values of array when values are in form of array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am doing in below way, is that method is fine or is that also possible with help of some functions. please suggest.

I have one array named **$items** and output is like below:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'value' => string '7' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'value' => string '14' (length=2)
```

But I need out put like below :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => int 7
  1 => int 14
```

And I did like this and got my required results:

```
    $new_array = array();
    foreach($items as $key=>$value){
     $new_array[] = $value['value'];
    }

var_dump($new_array);

array (size=2)
  0 => string '7' (length=1)
  1 => string '14' (length=2)
```

please suggest is this is right approach ?

Comment: `$new_array =  array_column($items, 'value');` - [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker   Thanks ! !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$newArray = array_map(function($value) { return (int)$value['value']; }, $items);
```

or as suggested in comments by @MarkBaker

```
$new_array = array_column($items, 'value');
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just looking like to convert with some function like you did and without foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

php `int()` casts a value to int ,just use it

```
 $new_array = array();
    foreach($items as $key=>$value){
     $new_array[] = (int)$value['value'];
    }

var_dump($new_array);
```